# How to remove google analytics code from CSV

Tags: regex, csv, replace, google-analytics

I have a CSV file that has 3 columns: Site ID, HTML Header, HTML Footer

I need to go through the HTML Header and Footer columns and locate any version of the Google Analytics tracking code, and remove it, but leaving anything else in those cells intact.

I tried using this regex: `<script(?m:.*?)\'UA-.{8,12}\'(?m:.*?)</script>` but it seems to be getting thrown off and removing too much, probably from some malformed code somewhere in the CSV.

Any ideas on a better way to do this?

Comment: By using an HTML parser? Also, are you doing this in Ruby? Otherwise `m` is the wrong flag. In any case, please specify your programming language.

Comment: I was trying to do it just using the regex find/replace in textmate on OSX.

Comment: Well if it's just a hacky one-off thing you could try something like replacing the two `.*?` with `(?:(?!</?script).)*`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, and from that I see how to tweak it further if needed. Thanks, if you add it as an answer, ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick hacky one-off replacement, you can probably fix it by avoiding ungreedy repetition and excluding `<script` or `</script` from the allowed sequences within the repetition. Replace both `.*?` with

```
(?:(?!</?script).)*
```